# php and mysql session destroyed before update

Tags: php, mysql

so im trying to have a table that shows which users are online on my site I have everything working besides the part where if someone closes the site without logging out first they stay on the table as logged in. i'll try to eplain my situation the best I can.

in my database I have a users table in that table is `online` when you login your `online` status is set to 1, when you click logout `online` is set to 0. here is the code im trying to use so that if someone is inactive for 10minutes they will be logged out ( `online` set to 0 )

```
<?php
session_start();
$timeout = 10; // Set timeout minutes
$logout_redirect_url = "logout.php"; // Set logout URL

$timeout = $timeout * 60; // Converts minutes to seconds
if (isset($_SESSION['last_activity'])) {
    $elapsed_time = time() - $_SESSION['last_activity'];
    if ($elapsed_time >= $timeout) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET online = 0 WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
        or die(mysql_error());
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: $logout_redirect_url");
    }
}
$_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
?>
```

This works fine it logs them out if they wait the 10minutes, but if they just close the browser it keeps `online` = 1 which displays them on the list.

I believe the problem is that when they close the browser that destroys the session before it gets the chance to update the users `online` and set it to 0

is there anyway around this? help would be very much appreciated thanks :)

btw I know not to use mysql anymore and everything, I will try to switch to something else once I learn more and get everything working first.

Comment: if you want the user out of your list. you have to check a copy of the users sessions on your side as a bulk and then kill each one after specific time. it's not that advance technique but still not noob one though

Comment: @mamdouh I am very new to all of this so I wouldnt know how to do anything of the sort :/ I'v only started learning a few days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem is that when a user closes their browser, there's no *reliable* way to first communicate with your server. [There are things you could try, but in my opinion that's a rabbit hole you shouldn't go down] All you really "know" is how recently the user visited your site logged-in. (in your case `$_SESSION['last_activity']`).

At a basic level, you will want to start persisting that information in your database, and then have a process kicked off occasionally to cleanup stale sessions.

e.g.

```
//On page load with a logged-in user
mysql_query("UPDATE `users`
             SET `last_activity` = '" . time() . "' 
             WHERE `username` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "'");
```

**note** that assumes you've added an `INT` column to your table named `last_activity`

and then in a process that executes, say, every 15 minutes:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` 
             SET `online` = 0 
             WHERE `last_activity` < '" . strtotime('-30 minutes') . "'");
```

Unix servers have something called **cron** especially for period tasks/scripts, so that's what I would recommend for kicking off your cleanup script.

Comment: oh that seems like it would work good thanks for this, but on the WHERE part of the first code what would I put there?

Comment: @user1908445 haha, i left that part out because, you seem to be keeping track of users by _username_, but I would recommend keeping tack of them by id (Primary Key). So, whatever identity token you are using to keep track of the user logged in on page load.

Comment: if im keeping track of them by username would I just make it? //On page load with a logged-id user
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `last_activity` = '" . time() . "' WHERE username=".$_SESSION['username']."");                             if I did it like this wouldnt I be in the same boat I was before its still killing the session on browser close so it wouldnt update that user.

Comment: @user1908445 answer updated to use your conventions for keeping track of users.

Comment: oh I understand now thanks alot you really saved me on this, been racking my brain for hours XD

Comment: I don't know if you'll come back to this question but the first code doesn't update the timestamp it sets it to 0-0-0-0-0000-00 or whatever the default is, it might be because its not set to an INT like you said but I tried to set it to an INT but it wouldnt let me

Comment: nvm I got it all working instead of time() and strtotime I used NOW()

Comment: @user1908445 you'll need to change the second snippet of code as well~ what field type are you using?

Comment: ok well I got most of it working fine, except now using this. mysql_query("UPDATE `users` 
             SET `online` = 0 
             WHERE `last_activity` < NOW('-11 minutes')"); it changes the users to 0 even if their time is not -11minutes I don't understand it :/

Comment: and im not using cron job, I just have it to run on page load on the page where it displays the list of online users.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22293/discussion-between-shad-and-user1908445)